# What hash function is used to cache credentials on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-10, hash

I am looking for the hash function used by Windows to cache user passwords locally on a computer. The client machine would run Windows 10. The AD Controller would run Windows Server 2016.